# Updating Google Map Using YM4R plugin link_to issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have my map working and displaying correctly. I trying to get it to update but I am running into issues.

From What I have gotten from searching on the web it seems to be easy to implement.

In my controller in the update I have

```
 def update
    @map = Variable.new("map")
    @marker = GMarker.new([75.89,-42.767],:title => "Update", :info_window => "I have been placed through RJS")
 end
```

In my update.rjs I have

```
page << @map.clear_overlays
page << @map.add_overlay(@marker)
```

In html.erb I am trying to set a link to this and I currently have the follow

```
<%=link_to "update", google_map_path(@google_map),:remote => true %>
```

The problem is for sure in the google_map_path(@google_map). My url to the update is wrong I am pretty sure resulting in the map not updating when I give it a new latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is an update method, perhaps the link should include a method something like this?

```
<%=link_to "update", google_map_path(@google_map), :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

What does the route look like?

Hi... I'm just updating this with an example from one of my projects. I'm not sure this will be any help at all, but at least you'll see what is expected. I have an rsvp controller.

In config/routes.rb I have this

```
resources :rsvps
```

In my view I have this:

```
<%=link_to "update", rsvp_path(@rsvp), :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

And this is the HTML that is rendered.

```
<a rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-method="put" href="/rsvps/4">update</a>
```

If you are getting an error about it finding the route, double check the name of the route that you want to use and make sure it is correct.

You can also test by manually entering the path with something like this:

```
<%=link_to "update", "/rsvps/#{@rsvp.id}", :method => :put, :remote => true %>
```

Once you get it to render the correct anchor to the page, then you can start trouble shooting the javascript for the ajax request.

Good luck.

Comment: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"google_map"} I am wondering why my route goes to show in two cases. for example I link to /google_map/index it gives me errors about show.html.erb. I just want my index to display the map(which it does) and update it without it going to a new page. I am pretty new so I may be doing a big beginners mistake

Comment: Do you have a line in your routes file that looks something like: 'resources :google_maps'? If you cd to the root of you application, and run rake routes, what output do you get?

Comment: The show method is the default path you will get when using the Get method. In your case, it sounds like there isn't a show method in your controller, so it returns the error. Changing to the put method should give you a path to update. When running rake routes, you should see something like: google_map PUT    /google_maps/:id(.:format)             {:action=>"update", :controller=>"google_maps"} as one of the routes.

Comment: Yes, I have 'resources :google_map' and when I do rake routes I have what stated  with the google_map PUT /google_maps /:id(.:format so on. I changed my link_to with the :method => :put and it complains about the route

Comment: Does the error happen when rendering the link? Or after you click on the link? What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: when I want to go to localhost:3000/google_map right away I getActionController::RoutingError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"google_map"} and points to the line <%=link_to "update", google_map(@google_map), :method=> :put, :remote=>true%>

Comment: do you have google_map_path(@google_map) or just google_map(@google_map). You can add _url or _path to the name of the route to get the url.

Comment: i have google_map_path(@google_map) when that error shows. I removed that line and just had :method => :put so: link_to "update, :method => :put, :remote => true and the site loaded but nothing happens to my map when I click the link which is probably cause the link is not reading the update method

Comment: Yeah, there won't be a URL in the link. You could try this just to see: <%=link_to "update", "/google_maps_or_your_path/#{@google_map.id}", :method => :put, :remote => true %>.

Comment: One more question, does your controller have a singular or a plural name? This can be something to look at too.